# How to send an object from client to server and reverse?

Tags: c#, sockets

Im having trouble sending an object through a socket in C#. I want to send an object which has a string and a type named 'MessageType', which contains an enum of different message types. This is the object:

```
public class Message
    {
        public MessageType Type { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    public enum MessageType
    {
        Hello,
        Welcome,
        BookInquiry,
        UserInquiry,
        BookInquiryReply,
        UserInquiryReply,
        EndCommunication,
        Error,
        NotFound,
    }
```

I want to send for example the Type Hello, which has Content: 'Client 0'.

This is what I got so far to send it:

```
public Output start()
        {
            int maxBuffSize = 1000;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[maxBuffSize];
            byte[] msg = new byte[maxBuffSize];
            string data = null;
            ConsoleKeyInfo key;


            
            settings.ServerPortNumber = 11111;

            this.serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(this.ipAddress, settings.ServerPortNumber);
            

            this.clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            this.clientSocket.Connect(this.serverEndPoint);

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to server");
                Console.WriteLine("\nSending hello message to server...");
                message.Type = MessageType.Hello;     //Here I specify the type of message
                message.Content = client_id;          //Here I specified the clientID
                Console.WriteLine("Message is", message.Content);
               
                if (message.Content != null)
                {

                    msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);    
                    clientSocket.Send(msg);          //How do I send the object message here?
                    int b = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);
                    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, b);

                    Console.WriteLine("" + data);
                    data = null;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n<< Continue 'y' , Exit 'e'>>\n");
                key = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key.KeyChar == 'e')
                {
                    clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Closed"));
                    Console.WriteLine("\nExiting.. Press any key to continue");
                    key = Console.ReadKey();
                    clientSocket.Close();
                    break;
                }

            }
            





            return result;
        }

    }
```

I tried converting the message object to a byte array and send it but then I got an error that it cant serialize it. I would like an easy to understand solution. I tried searching on internet but no success.

Comment: Look at using protobufs

Comment: Where 'data' is set for send? It's a matter of serialization. If you need to convert an object into a string and viceversa, you need a serializer/deserializer (NewtonJson, .Net Json, XML...) or implement your own logic.

Answer (score 0):

The serialization part could be done using the XML serializer:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new(typeof(Message));
using (MemoryStream ms = new())
{
    xs.Serialize(ms, msg);
    var bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Sending an array of bytes via a Socket can be done as follows:

```
var bytesSent = clientSocket.Send(bytes.AsMemory());
// Caveat: Not all bytes are guaranteed to have been sent
```

However, reading that variable-sized object and subsequently deserializing it at the other end of the TCP connection is substantially more complicated.

There are a million and one edge cases with `Socket()` programming, I strongly suggest that you look at using `gRPC` instead.  [gRPC services with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/basics?view=aspnetcore-5.0)